# Trim extra spaces in AWK

Tags: bash, awk

I have this AWK script.

```
awk -v line="    foo    bar  " 'END
 {
   gsub(/^ +| +$/,"", line);
   gsub(/ {2,}/, " ", line);
   print line
 }' \
somefile.txt
```

The input file (somefile.txt) is irrelevant to my question. The part that goes after the `END` pattern is there to **trim extra spaces** in the `line` variable and print it out. Like this:

```
foo bar
```

I'm trying to see if there is a better, more compact way to do that in AWK. Using `gsub` to remove a couple of extra spaces is very cumbersome. It is hard to read and hard for a maintainer to understand what it does (especially if one never worked with AWK before). Any ideas on how to make it shorter or more explicit?

Thanks!

** **EDIT** **

AWK variable `line` is filtered during the awk processing of the input file and I want to trim extra spaces left after that.

Comment: Why not `awk '{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf (i>1) ? " %s" : "%s", $i; print ""}' <<< "    foo    bar  "` The result is `"foo bar"`

Comment: Or `awk '{gsub(/[ ][ ]+/," "); gsub(/^[ ]/,"")}1' <<< "    foo    bar  "`

Comment: Thank you for all your suggestions! However, they don't make the script more readable and compact. I would try to avoid that example with a for loop because it makes the situation even more confusing.

Comment: Isn't there something like `END { trim(line); print line }`? I was hoping for that :)

Comment: @MishaSlyusarev, there isn't `trim` function(by literal name I mean) out of the box in `awk`, we have `gsub` OR `sub` for that which I mentioned in my answer(OR David's answer) and I have also explained that we need not to use `END` block in this program this could be taken care in `BEGIN` section itself IMHO.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @RavinderSingh13. There is no need to focus on whether it is in the end or beginning. I work on the line variable in the part of the script that is not shown and I want to trim it in the end. The question, again, is about how to make the trimming part more compact.

Comment: Why don't you preprocess this string before passing it to `awk`? You could, for instance: `line="    foo    bar  "; line=($line); awk -vline="${line[*]}" ...`.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet as shown in my example, I need to trim the line at the end of the processing, not before I give the line to the script. It is examples of modifying the script to use BEGIN that made it confusing for you. When the script receives the line it is perfectly fine. Then I work on it and at the end, I want to trim extra spaces.

Comment: @MishaSlyusarev Ah, I see. May I suggest that you add something about this in your question? Something explaining that awk variable `line` is built during the awk processing of the input file, not passed as you show and not read from standard input?

Comment: Do you want a solution that'll work for any value of `FS` or only for the default value of `FS`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the current example, another option might be to [recalculate the text](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Changing-Fields.html) of the input record by first setting the value of line to the input record and then use `$1=$1`

```
awk -v line="    foo    bar  " 'END {$0=line; $1=$1; print}' somefile.txt
```

Output (the quotes are only for clarity that there are no leading or trailing spaces)

```
"foo bar"
```

The inner workings how the spaces are removed are described in the comments by Ed Morton:

Setting `$0=line` or any other change to `$0` would trigger the **fields** being recalculated.

Using `$1=$1` triggers the **record** to be recalculated in as much as it'll be rebuilt from the existing fields thereby stripping leading/trailing white space and replacing every other chain of contiguous white space with a single blank char (assuming the default FS and OFS are used).

Comment: Yes, that's it. In my humble opinion your solution is the best of all, even if not necessarily the easiest to understand for `awk` beginners ;-).

Comment: This seems to be working! Could you add some explanation to the answer please? I assume that when you do `$0=line`, it strips off all unwanted spaces, and then you print it out as a default argument to `print`. But why do you need `$1=$1`?

Comment: @MishaSlyusarev `$0=line` does not strip of the unwanted spaces, it sets the value to the input record, and `$1=$1` will trigger that the fields are recalculated.

Answer (score 6):

Another option using `gsub()` as you began to do can be done as:

```sh
awk '{gsub(/  +/," "); sub(/^ /,""); sub(/ $/,"")}1' <<< "    foo    bar  "
```

Where the first call to `gsub()` consolidates all multiple spaces to a single space before/between the fields. The second `sub(/^ /,"")` just trims the single space that remains at the front of the string, and finally the last `sub(/ $/,"")` trims the trailing space.

Either approach works well. Depending on your actual data and your `FS` value, there may be a preference for one over the other, but without knowing more, they are pretty much a wash.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ awk '{gsub(/  +/," "); sub(/^ /,""); sub(/ $/,"")}1' <<< "    foo    bar  "
foo bar
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm on [@DavidC.Rankin's comment's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71153924/trim-extra-spaces-in-awk/71154025#comment125777316_71153924) path with:

```
$ awk  -v line="    foo    bar  " '
BEGIN {
    $0=line
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
        printf "%s%s",$i,(i==NF?ORS:OFS)
}'
```

Output:

```
foo bar
```

Comment: Nice use of the ternary in `(i==NF?ORS:OFS)`

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` program. Since you are having an `awk` variable and you are NOT reading any Input_file then we need NOT to use `END` block we could actually use `BEGIN` block itself in `awk` program to read variable.

In this `awk` program I am creating `awk` variable named `line` and in `BEGIN` section of this program I am globally substituting starting and ending spaces with NULL in line THEN globally substituting all occurrences of spaces(1 or more) with OFS(which is a single space itself) in variable `line`, then printing its value.

```
awk -v line="    foo    bar  " '
BEGIN{
  gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"",line)
  gsub(/[[:space:]]+/,OFS,line)
  print line
}
'
```

***OR*** Considering you have other functions/tasks/work happening in your `awk` program and you want to do trimming of variable in `END` section only then try following

```
awk -v line="    foo    bar  " '
END{
  gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"",line)
  gsub(/[[:space:]]+/,OFS,line)
  print line
}
'  Input_file
```

Comment: Nice incorporation of the variable and processing in `BEGIN`. I was a little bewildered by the `somefile.txt` at the end -- but I think that was there to be intentionally bewildering `:)`

Comment: The file is irrelevant to my question, and it doesn't matter whether I do it in the end or the beginning. What matters is how to make the trimming more compact. But thanks for the example!

Comment: Your last example is not going to work because the script expects file input. Also, this doesn't solve the problem, which is how to make that script more compact.

Comment: @MishaSlyusarev, If `END` block is present in `awk` code we need to mention Input_file name to it, I had missed it first time and added it later, should be Good now IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `split` function to collect all fields in an array and `substr` to remove the last leading space:

```sh
$ awk -vline="    foo    bar  " 'END {s = ""; l = split(line, a)
    for(i = 1; i <= l; i++) s = s " " a[i]; print substr(s, 2) "X"}' /dev/null
foo barX
```

The trailing `X` is here to show that the trailing spaces are also removed. Suppress it if you finally decide to use this. Other solution with `patsplit` instead of `split`:

```sh
$ awk -vline="    foo    bar  " 'END {s = ""; l = patsplit(line, a, /[^ ]+/)
    for(i = 1; i <= l; i++) s = s " " a[i]; print substr(s, 2) "X"}' /dev/null
foo barX
```

Comment: It should be part of the awk script because I'm working on the variable line (not shown in the example), and I want to trim it in the end.

Answer (score 1):

With any awk using any value of `FS` and any value of `OFS` if your spaces are all blank chars as handled by the code in your question, here's how to do it briefly and explicitly as requested in your question:

```
gsub(/ +/, " ", line)
gsub(/^ | $/, "", line)
```

For example, lets say you have a CSV and want to print the number of fields in each line followed by the fields separated by `|`s. A sample input file would be:

```
$ cat file
stuff,nonsense
```

and the awk script to process that would be:

```
$ awk -v FS=',' -v OFS='|' '
    { print NF, $1, $2 }
' file
2|stuff|nonsense
```

Now let's introduce your `line` variable and it's associated handling (I added `<` and `>` to the output to show that the leading/trailing spaces were stripped):

```
$ awk -v line='    foo    bar  ' -v FS=',' -v OFS='|' '
    { print NF, $1, $2 }
    END {
        gsub(/ +/, " ", line)
        gsub(/^ | $/, "", line)
        print "<" line ">"
    }
' file
2|stuff|nonsense
<foo bar>
```

and as you can see everything works exactly as intended while all of the other solutions posted so far would fail in various ways.

If the spaces in `line` aren't all blanks then using a POSIX awk for any type of white space characters in `line` (with a non-POSIX awk replace `[[:space:]]` with `[ \t]` to catch the most common chars of blank and tab, add others as you like):

```
gsub(/[[:space:]]+/, " ", line)
gsub(/^ | $/, "", line)
```

Your script:

```
gsub(/^ +| +$/,"", line);
gsub(/ {2,}/, " ", line);
```

was lengthier than it had to be because you're doing the gsub()s in the wrong order which necessitates the `+`s in the first one and unnecessarily checking for 2 or more blanks (`{2,}`) in the second one. It also wouldn't work if some of the spaces were tabs or some other white space characters.